# How to properly halve the inter-line distance in a math block environment

Tags: lengths, mathtools, dimensions, glue, dimension-expressions

... of `amsmath` or `mathtools`? In other words, how to properly halve  `\jot`?

Options:

```
\setlength{\jot}{.5\jot\relax}
\setlength{\jot}{\dimexpr.5\jot\relax}
\setlength{\jot}{\dimexpr\jot*.5\relax}
\setlength{\jot}{\dimexpr\jot/2\relax}
\setlength{\jot}{\glueexpr.5\jot\relax}
\setlength{\jot}{\glueexpr\jot*.5\relax}
\setlength{\jot}{\glueexpr\jot/2\relax}
```

Any other way?

I'm confused because apparently `\jot` also has some meaning in pure TeX, which I don't understand, and because amsmath documentation does not mention `\jot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually a `\jot` is a dimen register so `\dimexpr` would be more natural than `\gluexpr`  It is not a tex primitive, if that is what you mean by "pure tex" but it is defined in plain tex and latex by

```
\newdimen\jot
\jot=3pt
```

so you could just define it to be 1.5pt, (if it hasn't already been changed) or any of those etex expressions or the classic tex

```
 \divide\jot by 2
```

or

```
 \jot=.5\jot
```

Comment: @Just_A_Man they are identical in this case